# Why won't items post to my SharePoint list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am attempting to move data from a JSON format to a SharePoint list. The database that I am pulling the JSON from has a limit of 500 items per request so I am using EPOCH time to make multiple calls to pull all of the data. I am able to pull all of the data perfectly fine, but when I attempt to place it into the SharePoint list, I start to encounter problems. The first 515 items will be added to the SharePoint list without any issue, but any other items after that will not go into the SharePoint list. The last EPOCH time that will go into the SharePoint list is 1523302307, any item with an EPOCH time that is greater than that will not be placed into the list for some reason.

When the item does not get added to the SharePoint list, the`OnQueryFailed()` function says,

> **Request failed. Column '' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.**

A snippet of my code is below.

```
function testDatabase() {
    var settingObj = {
        sinceDateTime: '0',
        dynoCode: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx',
        custCode: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx',
        formGUID: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx',
        getJSONURL: 'https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.net/api/api/xxxx'
    };
    var columnArray = ['Quandrant', 'MapNumber', 'Picture1', 'Picture2', 'PoleOwner', 'PoleClass', 'PoleSize', 'PowerTagNumber', 'TelephoneTagNumber', 'AttachmentHeight', 'Guying', 'StreetLightAttached', 'TransformerPole', 'ExistingFiber', 'ExistingCopper', 'Grounds', 'MR1AtMidspanClearanceViolation', 'MR1ClearanceViolation', 'MR2PoleTransferRequired', 'MR3DownguyOrAnchorDeficiency', 'MR4BrokenLashingWire', 'MR5DamagedOrKinkedCoaxOrFiber', 'MR6DropTransferRequired', 'MR7TemporaryCoaxOrFiberCable', 'MR8DamagedElectronics', 'MR9PlaceOrRepairGroundOrBond', 'MR10DrpSplttrOrInsfntTapPrts', 'MR11PedOrVltOrLockbxDmged', 'PoleReplacement', 'PoleGrade', 'HouseCount', 'BuildingInformation'];
    $.getJSON(settingObj.getJSONURL, {
        sinceDateTime: settingObj.sinceDateTime,
        custCode: settingObj.custCode,
        dynoCode: settingObj.dynoCode,
        formGUID: settingObj.formGUID
    }).done(function (data) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('testlist2');
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var contentArray = data[i].FormFieldsList;
            this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
            this.oListItem.set_item('Title', data[i].resourceName);
            this.oListItem.set_item('SinceDateTime', data[i].FormUpdatedDate);
            var self = this;
            $.each(contentArray, function (i1, item2) {
                self.oListItem.set_item(columnArray[i1], contentArray[i1].FieldValue);
                console.log(contentArray[i1].FieldValue);
            });
            this.oListItem.update();
            clientContext.load(this.oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
        });
        console.log('Rows returned: ' + data.length);
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        console.log('Error on web service call: ' + err + ' Text Status: ' + textStatus + ' Message: ' + jqXHR.responseXML);
    });
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    console.log('Item created!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue! The dataset that I was importing had items with 32 columns which matched my array that I created, but then after the 515th item, the dataset switched to having 33 columns which explains the error I am receiving. Just thought I should post my answer in case anyone has this issue in the future.